# how to skip empty get parameter in django

Tags: django

I have URL like `www.example.com/search?param1=abc&param2=xyz&param3=`, currently what I'm doing in views is something like this.

```
if ((request.GET.get('param1')) or (request.GET.get('param2')) or (request.GET.get('param3'))):  
    if request.GET.get('param1'):
        value1 = request.GET.get('param1')
    if request.GET.get('title'):
        value2 = request.GET.get('param2')
    if request.GET.get('location'):
        value3 = request.GET.get('param3')

api_url = `www.api-end-point.com?p1=value1&p2=value2&p3=value3&format=json`
```

But you guys can see param3 is empty ,and to hit api i need to skip empty parameters.

So My question is how can i get all the set parameter from url in `GET` request in django.

Comment: have you tried using default parameter if nothing passed?

Comment: @Gahan I did n't get it what u r saying, actually this is my first project and i have n't heard about default parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# values = [request.GET.get(p) for p in ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']]
values = ['val1', 'val2', '']
names = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
query = 'www.api-end-point.com?'

for i, value in enumerate([v for v in values if v]):
    query += "{}{}={}".format("&" if i else "", names[i], value)

query += '&format=json'
```

which will yield:

`www.api-end-point.com?p1=val1&p2=val2&format=json`

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

`value1 = request.GET.get('param1') if request.GET.get('param1') else None`

Comment: don't you think its almost same `if request.GET.get('param1'):
        value1 = request.GET.get('param1')
else value1 = None`

Comment: no, it always create variable in your case variable not definition.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of uneven `&`s and redundant `p1=`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = {k: request.GET[k] for k in request.GET if request.GET[k]}
```